# Change value of a cell based on today`s date

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change the value of a cell based on today's date and a date found in another column.

Column N captures the date an issue was opened and column H captures the status (open, closed, carried).

I'd like status to change to carried once the open date is no longer in the same month as today's date.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include it in your post.

Comment: HI @Melissa, you better tell us what you have tried, and if possible also add an example of your data

Comment: I'm really new to VBA; everything I've been able to do has been in reference to awesome platforms like this :) and I haven't been able to find a starting point for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some more info in your post. However, as I only know two of your criteria’s, this chunk of code should set column H to either Open or Closed based on the date given in column N.

```
Sub Capture()

Dim ws as worksheet
Dim fRow as Long
Dim curDate as Date

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(“YourSheet”)
curDate = Now()

with ws
  fRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,13).end(xlUp).Row
End with

For i = 1 to fRow
With ws
    If .Cells(i, 13).Value > curDate Then
      .Cells(i, 8).Value = “Closed”
    Else
      .Cells(i, 8).Value = “Open”
  End if
End with
End sub
```